# Dual-booting Windows 7 and Windows 10 (with windows 10 installed first)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot

I have a laptop running in Windows 10 professional but for some reason I need to have access to windows 7. VM does not work in my case so I'm going to make it dual boot in my laptop.

I have gone through some website for information. However, most of them are tutorials on dual-booting with windows 7 installed before Windows 10. As I'm having the oppoisite (with windows 10 installed, and wanting windwos 7), is it still possible to make a dual boot on this laptop?

Comment: MS says no but with effort and 3rd party boot mgr's. and multiple partitions yes.  But you may want to backup and restore win7 from hidden partition and forget 10 till your next pc. MS allows 1 month after upgrade to revert.

Comment: Actually this is a new laptop purchased in Janurary and have been running Windows 10 since then. Can you provide more information on using the 3rd party tools? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see MS has a process now

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-windows-7-after/7e43130f-11a9-4167-832e-97ed168ae369